# Configuring ANT build file of a java project to support kotlin source classes

Tags: java, ant, kotlin

I am trying to add a kotlin class for an existing java project. I have replaced a java class with kotlin class and it works fine in the Intellij IDEA when I right click and say "recompile". But when I run my previously working ANT build task I am getting "Error: Cannot fine symbol" in the messages for my new kotlin code. Please point me to the right documentation order to get an idea of what exactly my problem is here.

Comment: It might help, if you can provide your ant build.xml file (or relevant excerpts) and your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the javac task to compile your sources, you have to add `<withKotlin />` to that task. You can find that in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-ant.html).
You will need to add `kotlin-ant.jar`.

Comment: I have done this. Still it the references to my kotlin classes from other java classes are not working. I do not see any error in the IDE. Only during the ant build.

Comment: Are you by any chance using the attribute fork="yes" on the javac task? I found that to be incompatible with kotlin.